# npm unable to install package and dependencies window 8.1

Tags: node.js, npm, package, windows-8.1

I installed nodejs in window 8.1 then I tried to install package (sailsjs,node-xmpp) package but I'm getting this error: 
The system cannot find the path specified.
 gyp ERR! configure error 
my node version is :

```
{ http_parser: '1.0',
node: '0.10.36',
v8: '3.14.5.9',
ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
uv: '0.10.30',
zlib: '1.2.8',
modules: '11',
openssl: '1.0.1l',
npm: '1.4.28',
'node-xmpp-client': '1.0.0-alpha20' 
}
```

[Error Image 1](https://github.com/vishnumishra/xmpp/blob/master/nodeError1.PNG) 
[Error Image 2](https://github.com/vishnumishra/xmpp/blob/master/nodeError2.PNG)

and also when I'm checking global directory
there is lot's of unmet dependency

> npm ls -g 
>   npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
>   npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined

and lot's of errors.

> npm ERR! missing: node-expat@>=1.4.1, required by node-xmpp@1.0.0-alpha2
>   npm ERR! missing: node-expat@>=1.4.1, required by ltx@0.9.0
>   npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@^1.1.0, required by has-ansi@1.0.3
>   npm ERR! missing: get-stdin@^4.0.1, required by has-ansi@1.0.3
>   npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@^1.0.0, required by strip-ansi@2.0.1
>   ......
>   npm ERR! not ok code 0

Plzz Help me..

Comment: The gyp build is related to some package not installed, therefore cannot build. see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp Basically need some python working with windows enviroment. The dependency issue may be fixed once your gyp is able to build.

Comment: @Evilsanta I rebuild the gyp but still problem exist.